# UserWarning: no type annotations present -- not typechecking __main__.my_func warn('no type annotations present -- not typechecking {}'.format(functio

Tags: python-3.x, typechecking, typeguards, typechecked

## Why is typeguard not typechecking a function?

The function works without the `@typechecked` decorator. Running with it gives a warning, stating no type checking is performed.

```
from typeguard import typechecked


@typechecked
def my_func(x, y):
    z = x + y
    return z


a = my_func(1, 2)
print(a)
```

```
(venv) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ python3 foo/bar.py 
/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typeguard/__init__.py:1016: UserWarning: no type annotations present -- not typechecking __main__.my_func
  warn('no type annotations present -- not typechecking {}'.format(function_name(func)))
1 2
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, [typeguard](https://pypi.org/project/typeguard/) will ignore the contents of any function objects that don't have type annotations.

To ensure `typechecking`, you must include type hints on the function's defined arguments.

```
from typeguard import typechecked


@typechecked
def my_func(x: int, y: int):
    z = x + y
    return z


a = my_func(1, 2)
print(a)
```

```
(venv) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ python3 foo/bar.py 
3
```